# How to set color and the name of series about the excel line chart created by Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, charts

I'm going to set color and the name of three series with the line chart in Apache POI. According to the following example, the names of each line are just `series 1`, `series 2` and `series 3` and the colors are automatically assigned. How can I modify the color and the name of them at the chart?

http://thinktibits.blogspot.hk/2014/07/apache-poi-xlsx-line-chart-java-example.html

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.charts.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.charts.*;
/* Line Chart Example in Apache POI */

public class LineChart{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   /* Create a Workbook object that will hold the final chart */

       XSSFWorkbook my_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
       /* Create a worksheet object for the line chart.
       This worksheet will contain the chart */
       XSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_workbook.createSheet("LineChart_Example");

       /* Let us now create some test data for the chart */
       /* Later we can see how to get this test data from a CSV File or SQL Table */
       /* We use a 4 Row chart input with 5 columns each */

       for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 4; rowIndex++){

            /* Add a row that contains the chart data */
            XSSFRow my_row = my_worksheet.createRow((short)rowIndex);

            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < 5; colIndex++){

                 /* Define column values for the row that is created */
                 XSSFCell cell = my_row.createCell((short)colIndex);
                 cell.setCellValue(colIndex * (rowIndex + 1));
            }
        }               
        /* At the end of this step, we have a worksheet with test data, that we want to write into a chart */
        /* Create a drawing canvas on the worksheet */
        XSSFDrawing xlsx_drawing = my_worksheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        /* Define anchor points in the worksheet to position the chart */
        XSSFClientAnchor anchor = xlsx_drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15);
        /* Create the chart object based on the anchor point */
        XSSFChart my_line_chart = xlsx_drawing.createChart(anchor);
        /* Define legends for the line chart and set the position of the legend */
        XSSFChartLegend legend = my_line_chart.getOrCreateLegend();
        legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.BOTTOM);     
        /* Create data for the chart */
        LineChartData data = my_line_chart.getChartDataFactory().createLineChartData();     
        /* Define chart AXIS */
        ChartAxis bottomAxis = my_line_chart.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        ValueAxis leftAxis = my_line_chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
        leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);     
        /* Define Data sources for the chart */
        /* Set the right cell range that contain values for the chart */
        /* Pass the worksheet and cell range address as inputs */
        /* Cell Range Address is defined as First row, last row, first column, last column */
        ChartDataSource<Number> xs = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(my_worksheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 4));
        ChartDataSource<Number> ys1 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(my_worksheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, 4));
        ChartDataSource<Number> ys2 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(my_worksheet, new CellRangeAddress(2, 2, 0, 4));
        ChartDataSource<Number> ys3 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(my_worksheet, new CellRangeAddress(3, 3, 0, 4));
        /* Add chart data sources as data to the chart */
        data.addSerie(xs, ys1);
        data.addSerie(xs, ys2);
        data.addSerie(xs, ys3);
        /* Plot the chart with the inputs from data and chart axis */
        my_line_chart.plot(data, new ChartAxis[] { bottomAxis, leftAxis });
        /* Finally define FileOutputStream and write chart information */               
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("xlsx-line-chart.xlsx");
        my_workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the line color after you have plotted the chart:

```
/* Plot the chart with the inputs from data and chart axis */
my_line_chart.plot(data, new ChartAxis[]{bottomAxis, leftAxis});

Color col1 = new Color(233, 87, 162);
CTSolidColorFillProperties fillProp = CTSolidColorFillProperties.Factory.newInstance();
CTSRgbColor rgb = CTSRgbColor.Factory.newInstance();
rgb.setVal(new byte[]{(byte) col1.getRed(), (byte) col1.getGreen(), (byte) col1.getBlue()});
fillProp.setSrgbClr(rgb);

CTLineProperties lineProp = CTLineProperties.Factory.newInstance();
lineProp.setSolidFill(fillProp);
CTShapeProperties ctShapeProperties = CTShapeProperties.Factory.newInstance();
ctShapeProperties.setLn(lineProp);

my_line_chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartList().get(0).getSerList().get(0).setSpPr(ctShapeProperties);
```